# Why is my LED flickering when it is connected to a variable resistor, and it's resistance is at the minimum value

Tags: led, potentiometer

I am doing a simple breadboard circuit, with an LED, 3.3V power supply (a microcontroller connected to the PC will be the voltage source), a potentiometer, and a Voltmeter connected across the LED.

This is the schematic of the circuit
[image: schematic]

When I put the slider at the bottom, the LED's brightness is dim, and the voltage across it will be (Voltmeter reading): 1.791 V

When I put the slider just below the top, the LED lights very bright, and the Voltage across it will be: 2.103 V

but when I put the slider at the top position, the Voltage across the LED decreases to 1.962 V, and the LED starts to flicker.

Can someone help me with this issue?

**EDIT**
[image]
I hope the picture is clear, I am connecting the Launch Pad to the PC, and using its 3V3 pin, and GND pin as a voltage source to my circuit, there is no code, or digital output pin involved (launch pad is just a fancy battery)

Comment: You're not indicating where the slider is connected, but if it's to the ground side of the pot, you may be hitting the current limit of the output pin of the microcontroller.

Comment: @Forat: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar that your circuit gets saved inline with your post and can be edited and copied into the answers. You don't need an account. You don't need to screengrab. You don't need to upload images.

Comment: @PhilG has a good idea - it could also be the +3.3V regulator's internal thermal limiter that "flickers" on-and-off. It could be running very hot.

Comment: no I am not driving it through a microcontroller output pin, the launch pad is connected to the PC, and it have 2 pins a GND pin, and a 3V3 pin, I am just using it as a voltage source, I will take a picture and put it on the edit

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the comment, It was the first time I use CircuitLab, and I just drew the circuit, and insert it on the post. I will try to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be three reasons for this.

1, the slide pot is damaged or dirty at the top end. This could be dirt or something that is causing a physically bad connection, or the wiper of the pot is carrying too much current and causes it to flex. There is a maximum current it can carry before damage happens.

2, the led is drawing so much current it overheats and there is internal damage to the led die or bond wires and unstable flashing is a sign of this. At one end of the pot, it will be whatever resistance it should be, either 10k or whatever. The other end will be almost zero. So your overpowering that led.

3, the regulator is going into protection mode, along with reason 2, the led drawing too much current. So the regulator shuts itself off, then the led stops drawing power, then  the regulator turns on, rinse lather repeat. This explains the lower voltage your meter is reading because it's happening too fast for the meter to get accurately, and the flashing.

Comment: My LED was drawing too much current, I removed the Potentiometer and added the Launch Pad's voltage across it if flickered, I changed it with another LED, and there was no issue (My mistake should've checked before posting here).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're driving the LED with an output pin on your microcontroller you are probably sinking more current into your LED than the MCU can provide.  The flickering is likely your microcontroller browning out and resetting.

Comment: I am using my Launch Pad as a battery, I am not writing any code to drive a pin high. My launch pad is connected to the PC, which provides voltage to the LP, the LP have a 3.3 V pin and a GND pin, and I am using these pin to power my circuit